# How to allow for two separate key mappings for a single key (say Up) in CodeMirror, depending on scenario

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am creating a chrome extension that adds autocomplete to a CodeMirror instance (rolled out my own version of autocomplete for some reason) and the CodeMirror instance in question is v2.37, so relatively old.

All works, except that I want to use 'Enter','Up' and 'Down' for when the autocomplete is showing and thus select an entry or move up/down the list. The issue I have is that whilst it is easy to enable this when the autocomplete shows, it is currently also preventing the default action when it is not showing. This is the code I have:

```
editor.setOption("extraKeys", {
  "Enter": function(){
    if($('.CodeMirror-completions').length > 0) {
      var str = $('.CodeMirror-completions li.selected').text();
      var from = $('.CodeMirror-completions ul').data('from');
      var to = $('.CodeMirror-completions ul').data('to');
      editor.replaceRange(str, from, to);
      $('.CodeMirror-completions').remove();
      setTimeout(function(){editor.focus();}, 50);
      return editor.PASS;
    } else {
      CodeMirror.commands.newlineAndIndent(cm);
    }
  },
  "Up": function(){
    if($('.CodeMirror-completions').length > 0) {
      var divSelected = $('.CodeMirror-completions li.selected');
      var next = divSelected.prev('li');
      divSelected.removeClass('selected');
      if (next.length > 0){
        divSelected = next.addClass('selected');
      }
      return editor.PASS;
    } else {
      CodeMirror.commands.goLineUp(cm);
    }
  }
});
```

Interestingly enough, the 'Enter' one works fine, but the 'Up' one doesn't.

Initially I thought that this would work (in pseudo-code), but it doesn't:

```
"Enter": function(){
    if(autocomplete showing) {
      replaceRange()
      return editor.PASS;
    }
  }
```

Is there an equivalent of **editor.PASS** for basically saying use the default action for that key?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I made one simple error, omitting the 'cm' object from the first function >> `"Up": function(cm){` rather than `"Up": function(){` so it wasn't passed down.

full code:

```
"Up": function(cm){
  if($('.CodeMirror-completions').length > 0) {
    var divSelected = $('.CodeMirror-completions li.selected');
    var next = divSelected.prev('li');
    divSelected.removeClass('selected');
    if (next.length > 0){
      divSelected = next.addClass('selected');
    }
    return editor.PASS;
    }
    CodeMirror.commands.goLineUp(cm);
  }
```

Hopefully this will help anyone binding certain events to commonly used keymaps depending on the scenario in question.